# Lightning Flow Builder - Decision on Radio Button

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm currently working on a Flow that guides a User through creating a record.

For this I setup a simple screen with the radio button component. There are two choices set as resource: {!createGuide}, {!createGuideItem}

After this a decision-logic-component is supposed to decide which screen is called. However, I cannot get the decision to run properly.

**Flow**

[image]

**Setup of RadioButtons:**

[image]

**Setup of Choices:**

[image]

[image]

**Setup of Decision:**

[image]

Hopefully somebody can help

Answer (score 8):

I managed to solve the issue. In case anybody needs to know here's the way the solve:

- Leave 'Choice Value' empty on the choice empty
- Go to decision and set the Choice itself as resource and then select "Was Selected"
- The value then needs to set to GlobalConstant.True

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for this it solved my problem too.

Comment: So so helpful. So glad you shared this 3 years ago! Your gift keeps on giving. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking radio_welcomescreen equals chc_guidescreen, you have to check

**chc_guidescreen was selected true**

[image: You have to update the decision condition like below image]

Comment: This is so damn counterintuitive!